# Конвертация изображения в двоичное представление

Tags: php

Нужно сделать аналог операции как тут http://www.dcode.fr/binary-image
Т.е.   изображение в двоичное представление и обратно. 
Получить примерно такой результат:

```
11111111111111111111111111
11111100111111111100111111
11110001111100111110001111
11000001111000011110000011
10000000111000011100000001
10000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000001
10000110001000010001100001
11001111111100111111110011
11100111111100111111100111
11111111111111111111111111
```

И после его обратно в изображение.
Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Добавьте всю необходимую для понимания вопроса информацию в сам вопрос, а то ссылки могут перестать работать в будущем

Comment: И да, это не выглядит совсем уж сложным, вы пытались что-то сделать самостоятельно?

Answer (score 3):

По ссылке представлен обычный генератор ascii-art. Алгоритм его работы примерно такой: берется изображение, масштабируется, конвертируется в черно-белое, далее построчно берутся значения пикселей - если там черный, то рисуем 0, если белый - 1 (или наоборот).

Чтобы сконвертировать обратно в изображение: берется массив (если это строка, разбитая символами переноса строки, то делается explode по символу переноса строки), затем создается изображение, размерами высотой в количество элементов массива, а шириной - в длину самой длинной строки и заполнить изображение по принципу - 0 = черный пиксель, 1 = белый